# How to convert an activity to a fragment in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have this activity

```
package com.padilla.jorge.proyecto_aplicaciones_moviles;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;



public class VerPerfil extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] arraySpinner;
Intent i;
TextView Nombre_TextView;
TextView Email_TextView;
TextView Password_TextView;
TextView Puntos_TextView;

TextView getNombre;
TextView getEmail;
TextView getPassword;
TextView getPuntos;


ArrayList<TextView> textViewsVal;
ArrayList<TextView> textViewsName;

FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference reference;

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ver_perfil);
    Nombre_TextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Nombre_textView);
    Email_TextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Email_TextView);
    Password_TextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Password_TextView);
    Puntos_TextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Puntos_TextView);
    getNombre=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Nombre_valor);
    getEmail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Email_valor);
    getPassword=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Password_valor);
    getPuntos=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Puntos_valor);


    textViewsName = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    textViewsName.add(Nombre_TextView);
    textViewsName.add(Email_TextView);
    textViewsName.add(Password_TextView);
    textViewsName.add(Puntos_TextView);

    textViewsVal = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    textViewsVal.add(getNombre);
    textViewsVal.add(getEmail);
    textViewsVal.add(getPassword);
    textViewsVal.add(getPuntos);
    Intent name_intent=this.getIntent();
    final String name=name_intent.getExtras().getString("name");

    reference = database.getReference(name).child("Perfil");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //rutina.setText(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            int i = 0;
            Log.d("number of childs",""+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                if (i < 10) {
                    textViewsName.get(i).setText(child.getKey());
                    textViewsVal.get(i).setText(child.getValue().toString());
                    Log.d("User key", child.getKey());
                    Log.d("User ref", child.getRef().toString());
                    Log.d("User val", child.getValue().toString());
                    i++;
                }

            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}

}
```

and i was wondering if there's a simple way to convert it to a fragment? Any help would be appreciated. 
The reason i want to do this is because i want to implement a navigation drawer menu and i've seen that you have to use fragments (i know there's a way to do it with classes but it's way more complicated) and i already have this class so i would like to reuse it instead of creating a new fragment from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this:

1. Extend fragment and refactor `MyActivityClass` to `MyFragmentClass`

**original**: `public class MyActivityClass extends AppCompatActivity`
**converted**:   `public class MyFragmentClass extends Fragment`

2. Create factory method and add all the values that you get from `getIntent().getExtra()` as parameters for the method

**original**: `String name=getIntent.getExtras().getString("name");`

**converted**:

This

```
public static MyFragmentClass newInstance(String name){
    MyFragmentClass fragment = new MyActivity();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(KEY_NAME, name);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

and this,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        name = getArguments().getString(KEY_NAME);
    }
}
```

3. override method `onCreateView()` and inflate your layout

**original**: `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);`

**converted**:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_layout, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

4. place all the `findViewById(...);` statement in `onCreateView()` and rename to `view.findViewById(...)` and other code which does not need the activity to run.
5. override `onActivityCreated()` and place all the code that needs `Activty` in here.
6. remove code already converted to fragment

It's not the perfect answer but should help.

Answer (score -5):

Try this:

1. Create fragment
2. Move that code and layout to fragment instead
3. Now you have a reusable fragment
4. Add the fragment in your activity or navigation drawer or wherever you like

Comment: ok, but there are several parts of the code that change in the fragment, right? For example, I need a onCreateView() instead of just onCreate(). That's my question, how to accomodate my code into an empty fragment activity?